# Add param to link_to show method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the current code in my traders.index.html file

```
<ul>
<% @traders.each do |trader| %>
  <li><%= link_to trader.name, trader %></li>
<%end%>
</ul>
```

I want to add an extra parameter to be sent through, I tried

```
<li><%= link_to trader.name, trader, {:restricted => params[:s]} %></li>
```

But this doesn't send the parameter, whats the actual format of the link_to to get this done?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
<%= link_to trader.name, trader_path(trader, restricted: params[:s]) %>
```